# Lining up radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I am trying to line my radio button up with the rest of my form and I am also trying to make it so that the radio button text is in line with the radio button. I would also like a label to say cvType and then the buttons be beside that label. I have tried to use the `form-control` class but it makes my the buttons really big so I decided to take it out, any help would be appreciated

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>COM109 Web_Form</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="contact-title">
        <h1 >Contact Us</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="">

            <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your First Name" required><br>

            <input type="text" name="Surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Surname" required><br>

            <input type="text" name="CompanyName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Company Name" required><br>

            <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>

            Short <input type="radio" name="cvType" class="radio" value="Short">

            Long <input type="radio" name="cvType" class="radio" value="Long"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
background-color: #85CDCA;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.contact-title {
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contact-title h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 10px;
}

form {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.form-control {
    width: 600px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid Black;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 16px; 
    resize: none;
}

input{
    height: 45px;
}

form .submit{
    background: pink;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

form .submit:hover{
    background-color: peachpuff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Running example to show my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Darren_jr/x4oL1m32/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only want to specify the height for the input fields of type text, not for the radiobuttons. You can do that by using the css selector `input[type="text"]` instead of just `input` in line 36.

Comment: That fixed my issue with the buttons being massive, but now there is a lot of spacing between the text and button. For example it says short and then there is a massive gap, then there is the button then there is another massive gap and then it says long.

Comment: Have you edited something else? For me it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/h5t2Lqax/1/

Comment: I must have because I copied and pasted your code from jsfiddle and it fixed it. Would you be able to tell me how to write text to the left of those radio buttons and line them up with the rest of my form?

Comment: It's not really a beautiful solution, but it works: https://jsfiddle.net/m8u2znst/1/

Because you know, you want the form to be 600px wide, you can specify the width. `position: relative` in the `form` marks it as the anchor for the `left: 0` in the `span.description-text`. That way the text is on the left in the form.